# How correctly externalize SecurityGroupEgress and SecurityGroupIngress in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

With the below CloudFormation template I'm able to SSH into the EC2 instance.

```
PublicSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
        GroupName: PublicSecurityGroup
        GroupDescription: Public Security Group
        VpcId:
            Ref: Vpc
        SecurityGroupEgress:
            - IpProtocol: "-1"
                FromPort: 0
                ToPort: 65535
                CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        SecurityGroupIngress:
            - IpProtocol: tcp
                FromPort: 22
                ToPort: 22
                CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
PublicEc2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
        ImageId:
            Ref: ImageId
        InstanceType:
            Ref: InstanceType
        KeyName:
            Ref: KeyName
        SecurityGroupIds:
            - Fn::GetAtt:
                    - PublicSecurityGroup
                    - GroupId
        SubnetId:
            Ref: PublicSubnet
        Tags:
            - Key: Name
                Value: PublicEc2Instance
```

When I change the `SecurityGroup` definition to the below structure

```
PublicSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
        GroupName: PublicSecurityGroup
        GroupDescription: Public Security Group
        VpcId:
            Ref: Vpc
PublicOutboundRule1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress
    Properties:
        GroupId: !Ref PublicSecurityGroup
        SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref PublicSecurityGroup
        IpProtocol: "-1"
        FromPort: 0
        ToPort: 65535
PublicInboundRule1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
        GroupId: !Ref PublicSecurityGroup
        SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref PublicSecurityGroup
        IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
```

I'm not able to SSH in the EC2 instance any more.

Why does externalization of `SecurityGroupEgress` and `SecurityGroupIngress` blocks the SSH access to the EC2?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You restricted traffic in your ingress rule down to the `PublicSecurityGroup` in this line:
        `SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref PublicSecurityGroup`
Instead of `SourceSecurityGroupId` specify a CIDR block that you used in the upper yaml snippet:

```
PublicSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
        GroupName: PublicSecurityGroup
        GroupDescription: Public Security Group
        VpcId:
            Ref: Vpc
PublicOutboundRule1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress
    Properties:
        GroupId: !Ref PublicSecurityGroup
        IpProtocol: "-1"
        FromPort: 0
        ToPort: 65535
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

PublicInboundRule1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
        GroupId: !Ref PublicSecurityGroup
        IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Notice that I removed `SourceSecurityGroupId` from your Egress rule too, because Egress rules do not expect sources, they expect destinations (other SGs, CIDR blocks), because they are, well, egress :).

Comment: Hi Vladyslav! Thank you very much for your precise and very useful explanation. It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You are not establishing a correct relation between the AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup and AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress/AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress

In your first description your are allowing access to 22 port from any location:
`SecurityGroupIngress:
    - IpProtocol: tcp
         FromPort: 22
         ToPort: 22
         CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0`

But in your second definition your are defining access to port 22 only from the same Security Group, because the parameter SourceSecurityGroupId specifies the ID of the Amazon EC2 Security Group to allow access and you want to grant access from 0.0.0.0/, is not the same:

`SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref PublicSecurityGroup
 IpProtocol: tcp
 FromPort: 22
 ToPort: 22`

You need to remove the SourceSecurityGroupId parameter

Comment: Hi conde! You are right! I should not use SourceSecurityGroupId and use CidrIp instead. Thank you very much!